# Hash with MD5 in Java?

Tags: java, hash, cryptography, md5

I am creating one program that will take the user output of login and password and hash this variables(login and password).

When I hash the output from login It works but when I try hash the output from the password doens't work.

**Code :**

```
String login;
String password;


login = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Login : ");
password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Password : ");

MessageDigest m; 


try 
{ 
m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
m.update(login.getBytes(),0,login.length()); 
m.update(password.getBytes(),0,password.length());
BigInteger login1 = new BigInteger(1, m.digest()); 
BigInteger password1 = new BigInteger(1, m.digest());

login = String.format("%1$032X", login1); 
password = String.format("%1$032X", password1); 

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login : " + login + 
                "\nPassword : " + password);

//System.out.println("login : "+ login); 
//System.out.println("password : " + password);
}
```

**Output :**

```
login : E9CA9D798BA364DFF16C738D03AF6668
password : D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E
```

The variable login goes normal,but the password always do the same result when hashing,I want to make the variable password always get some different result when hashing.

**PS : Sorry for the bad English,not my native language.**

Comment: You are calling `m.digest()` twice in a row...

Comment: I can't just use the same ? Or I will need to create a new one ? Because I already tried and didn't worked.For example when I create another MessageDigest called m1,m1 will follows the same result from m.digest() when hashing.

Comment: You shouldn't be using MD5 anymore for password hashing, it's cryptographically weak. Instead use something like bcrypt.

Comment: I know that,but It's for one lesson from the course that I am doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment you are calling the digest twice without a reset. You need to reset the digest before next use.

```
try
{
    m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    m.update(login.getBytes(), 0, login.length());
    BigInteger login1 = new BigInteger(1, m.digest());
    login = String.format("%1$032X", login1);

    m.reset(); // <---- Reset before doing the password
    m.update(password.getBytes(), 0, password.length());
    BigInteger password1 = new BigInteger(1, m.digest());
    password = String.format("%1$032X", password1);

    System.out.println(login);
    System.out.println(password);
}
```

Comment: Didn't worked,It does the same thing that happens when I try with the another code.The two variables follows the same result together.

Comment: No, your first code was always giving the same MD5 hash for the password no matter what the password was. My code is giving a new hash for each password. Change the password and you will get a new hash :)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are retrieving your password from a web element rather than extracting the string directly for hashing. D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E is the md5sum of "nothing" (a zero-length stream of characters). Usually in html(html5) the password fields are intelligent enough not to give away data, may be that is why you are getting a null string in return. Hope this helps

Comment: That wouldn't even matter. His code was giving the same MD5 hash no matter what the password was.